# Empty variardic packs of enums -- do they make two functions different?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer, sfinae

There is a technique I sometimes use when overriding `template` functions that goes like this:

```
#include <utility>
template<int> struct unique_enum { enum class type {}; };
template<int index> using UniqueEnum = typename unique_enum<index>::type;
template<bool b, int index=1>
using EnableFuncIf = typename std::enable_if< b, UniqueEnum<index> >::type;
template<bool b, int index=1>
using DisableFuncIf = EnableFuncIf<!b, -index>;

// boring traits class:
template<typename T>
struct is_int : std::false_type {};
template<>
struct is_int<int> : std::true_type {};

#include <iostream>
// use empty variardic packs to give these two SFINAE functions different signatures:
template<typename C, EnableFuncIf< is_int<C>::value >...>
void do_stuff() {
  std::cout << "int!\n";
}
template<typename C, DisableFuncIf< is_int<C>::value >...>
void do_stuff() {
  std::cout << "not int!\n";
}

int main() {
  do_stuff<int>();
  do_stuff<double>();
}
```

This distinguishes `do_stuff` from `do_stuff`, because one takes 0 or more `UniqueEnum<1>`s, and the other takes 0 or more `UniqueEnum<-1>`s.  gcc 4.8 considers these different empty packs to be distinct.

However, in the latest version of clang I tried, this fails: it treats the function with 0 `UniqueEnum<1>`s as being the same as the function with 0 `UniqueEnum<-1>`s.

There are easy workarounds that work in clang, but I'm wondering if my above technique is legal -- do two function `template`s, which differ only by empty variardic parameter packs, actually different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think GCC is right, and your technique is correct. Basically, since the type argument for `C` is specified explicitly, the question is whether:

a. substitution of `C` everywhere else in the function template signature happens first, and then type deduction is performed (which should result in a substitution failure); or

b. type deduction is performed first, and then substitution is performed (which would not result in a substitution failure, because the corresponding argument pack would be empty, and so there would be no substitution to perform).

It seems GCC assumes (1), while Clang assumes (2). Paragraph 14.8.2/2 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> When an explicit template argument list is specified, the template arguments must be compatible with the
>   template parameter list and must result in a valid function type as described below; otherwise type deduction
>   fails. Specifically, **the following steps are performed** when evaluating an explicitly specified template
>   argument list with respect to a given function template:
>
> — The specified template arguments must match the template parameters in kind (i.e., type, non-type,
>   template). There must not be more arguments than there are parameters unless at least one parameter
>   is a template parameter pack, and there shall be an argument for each non-pack parameter. Otherwise,
>   type deduction fails.
>
> — Non-type arguments must match the types of the corresponding non-type template parameters, or must
>   be convertible to the types of the corresponding non-type parameters as specified in 14.3.2, otherwise
>   type deduction fails.
>
> — **The specified template argument values are substituted for the corresponding template parameters as
>   specified below**.

The following paragraph then says:

> After this substitution is performed, the function parameter type adjustments described in 8.3.5 are performed. [...]

Moreover, paragraph 14.8.2/5 specifies:

> The resulting substituted and adjusted function type **is used as the type of the function template for template
>   argument deduction**. [...]

Finally, paragraph 14.8.2/6 goes as follows:

> At certain points in the template argument deduction process it is necessary to take a function type that
>   makes use of template parameters and replace those template parameters with the corresponding template
>   arguments. **This is done at the beginning of template argument deduction when any explicitly specified template
>   arguments are substituted into the function type**, and again at the end of template argument deduction
>   when any template arguments that were deduced or obtained from default arguments are substituted.

This all seems to imply that first substitution is performed, then template argument deduction. Hence, a substitution failure should occur in either case and one of the two templates should be discarded from the overload set.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a clear specification as to what the behavior should be when templates arguments are deduced rather than being explicitly specified.

Comment: Does this only apply when we specify the argument explicitly, and not deduce it?  (ie, had I made the function take `T const&`, then passed `7` to it, would the trick no longer be legal?)

Comment: @Yakk: In that case I'm not exactly sure, but I've read through the whole 14.8.2 several times and it seems to me the Standard does not specify what the behavior should be